# Python package only works as admin

Tags: python

On Mac OSX 10.6 I installed the music21 package for python by using

`python setup.py install`

in the directory named in

`distutils.sysconfig.get_python_lib()`

which was

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages`

Now, if I run Python as an admin, like

`sudo python`

then I can get at the package:

`>> import music21`

but if I run Python without admin privileges, Python cannot find the package.  Has anyone encountered this problem?  I have verified that the library files are in the right place (namely, a subdirectory `music21` of `site-packages`).  If I do

`chmod -R a+r *`

in this directory, it finds the package but throws an exception during importing.  Does anyone have any advice?

EDIT:  This is the output of Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/music21/__init__.py", line 80, in <module>
    import base
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/music21/base.py", line 60, in <module>
    from music21 import tie
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/music21/tie.py", line 16, in <module>
    from music21.musicxml import translate as musicxmlTranslate
ImportError: No module named musicxml
```

It seems to me as though I'm not chmod-ing everything that needs to be chmodded.  Shouldn't there be a simple way that configures everything for a regular user?

Comment: What's the exception in the last para?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix systems, the `r` privilege on a directory lets you see properties of the directory itself, but you need the `x` privilege to be allowed to list its contents. Therefore, try doing the following:

```
chmod -R a+rX *
```

In contrast to `a+x` (lowercase x), which means "make every file executable and directory list-able to everyone", `a+X` (uppercase x) means "make every file executable and directory list-able to everyone if the `x` privilege is already to set to at least one of user, group and other".

If, therefore, the privileges are, for example, `rw-r--r--`, they won't be changed, but if they are `rw-r-xr--`, they will become `rwxr-xr-x` (because `x` had been set for group).